I get NaN values when I calculate one DataFrame to give Results for another Dataframe. How do I fix this?
I created a dictionary for my DataFrame object. I created a function to calculate the number of days worked and the overtime that was worked in from the hours per worked per week in the DataFrame. Then I calculate the Hours worked per week against the variables i defined and created a new DataFrame from these answers. Then I merge the two DataFrames together but The result is wrong, because of merging the data accordingly it merges the data by adding onto the list. How can I fix this? I need the results DataFrame to Correspond to the data DataFrame next to each other. for example employee id 1 worked in a remote site for 29 hours per week the number of days worked and overtime worked does not correspond. How can I fix all this?
import pandas as pd 

data = {
    'Employee_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'Employment_Type': ['Remote', 'In-Office', 'Remote', 'Remote', 'Remote'], 
    'Hours_Worked_Per_Week': [29.0, 45.0, 34.0, 25.0, 50.0]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def calculate_days_and_overtime(df):
    results = [] 

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            total_hours = row['Hours_Worked_Per_Week']
            regular_hours_per_day = 8 
            days_per_week = 5
            total_regular_hours = days_per_week * regular_hours_per_day
            overtime = max(0, total_hours - total_regular_hours)

            regular_days = min(days_per_week, total_hours // regular_hours_per_day)
            total_hours -= regular_days * regular_hours_per_day

            overtime_days = overtime // regular_hours_per_day
            remaining_overtime_hours = overtime % regular_hours_per_day

            total_days_worked = regular_days + overtime_days + (1 if remaining_overtime_hours else 0)
            
            results.append({
                'Employee_ID'               : row['Employee_ID'],
                'Regular Days'              : regular_days, 
                'Overtime Days'             : overtime_days, 
                'Remaining Overtime Hours'  : remaining_overtime_hours, 
                'Total Days Worked'         : total_days_worked, 
                'Work Location'             : row['Employment_Type']
            })

        return pd.DataFrame(results)
    
results_df = calculate_days_and_overtime(df)
merged_df = pd.concat([df, results_df], ignore_index=True)
merged_df


import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Employee_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Employment_Type': ['Remote', 'In-Office', 'Remote', 'Remote', 'Remote'],
    'Hours_Worked_Per_Week': [29.0, 45.0, 34.0, 25.0, 50.0]
}

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def calculate_days_and_overtime(df):
    results = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        total_hours = row['Hours_Worked_Per_Week']
        regular_hours_per_day = 8
        days_per_week = 5
        total_regular_hours = days_per_week * regular_hours_per_day
        overtime = max(0, total_hours - total_regular_hours)

        regular_days = min(days_per_week, total_hours // regular_hours_per_day)
        total_hours -= regular_days * regular_hours_per_day

        overtime_days = overtime // regular_hours_per_day
        remaining_overtime_hours = overtime % regular_hours_per_day

        total_days_worked = regular_days + overtime_days + (1 if remaining_overtime_hours else 0)

        results.append({
            'Employee_ID': row['Employee_ID'],
            'Regular Days': regular_days,
            'Overtime Days': overtime_days,
            'Remaining Overtime Hours': remaining_overtime_hours,
            'Total Days Worked': total_days_worked,
            'Work Location': row['Employment_Type']
        })

    return pd.DataFrame(results)


print("=== df ===")
print(df)
results_df = calculate_days_and_overtime(df)
print("=== results_df ===")
print(results_df)
merged_df = pd.merge(df, results_df, on='Employee_ID')
print("=== merged_df ===")
print(merged_df)


Also note that, a unique identifier must be used with the pd.merge() function. This will prevent python to add more records to your DataFrame. For example, if the 'Work Location' column was used as an identifier in the pd.merge() function. Then all of the records would have been added as a merge. I don't know if you understand. But try this, switch the pd.merge(on='') with any of the columns as idenetifiers, because they are non-unique more rows will be added to the DataFrame. So always use a unique identifier when working with the pd.merge() function.
